# How to use ftp command to get files on remote unix?

Tags: windows, unix, ftp

I run a putty to connect to a remote unix server.
How can I down load files in that server to local windows directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putty provides pscp and psftp commands.  If they aren't in your local install you can find them at the [PuTTY download page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) for this purpose.